# What does "generic" mean in this context, and is it related to generic points in algebraic geometry?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry

In "The characteristic polynomial and determinant are not ad hoc constructions" by Skip Garibaldi, available at

http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0203276

the characteristic polynomial is defined as the minimal polynomial of a "generic element."  Specifically, this is the setup:

> Let $F$ be a field and $A$ a finite-dimensional $F$-algebra.
>
> Let $\{a_1, \ldots, a_m\}$ be an $F$-basis for $A$.
>
> Let $R = F[t_1, \ldots, t_m]$ and $K = \operatorname{Frac} R = F(t_1,
> > \ldots, t_m)$.
>
> Consider $\gamma = \sum_i a_i \otimes t_i \in A \otimes_F K$, which we
>   call a *generic element*.
>
> Since $A \otimes_F K$ is a finite-dimensional $K$-vector space,
>   $\operatorname{span} \{1, \gamma, \gamma^2, \ldots \}$ is
>   finite-dimensional, so $\gamma$ has a minimal polynomial $m \in K[x]$,
>   and it's easy to see that in fact $m \in R[x]$.  We define the
>   characteristic polynomial of $a = \sum_i c_i a_i \in A$ to be the
>   image of $m$ under the map $R[x] \to F[x]$ given by $t_i \mapsto c_i$.

This is a nice argument, but it still feels a bit ad-hoc to me: we have to explicitly calculate that doesn't rely on the choice of $F$-basis, for instance, and why is $\gamma$ specifically a "generic" element of $A \otimes_F K$?

I mean, I understand the idea of taking a matrix filled with indeterminates and computing its minimal polynomial, but it doesn't seem to be a natural thing to do from a purely algebraic perspective.

Is there some way to rephrase this argument so that we can view $A$ as having a scheme structure and to regard $m$ as the "minimal polynomial of the generic point" or something of the sort?  I've tried a couple things but just get to a point where it seems like we're commingling elements of a -- is it called an "algebra scheme?" -- together with functions on it, and I get confused by the whole thing.  But that could just be my inexperience.

Comment: It _is_ very natural! What better way to prove an algebraic identity than to prove the generic instance of it? And yes, it is closely related to the notion of generic point; though it is not the generic point of $A$ we are considering here, but rather than of $A \otimes_K R$.

Comment: Re: "What better way to prove an algebraic identity than to prove the generic instance of it?"

I meant "natural" in a more categorical sense, I guess.  If the definition doesn't depend on the choice of basis, we should be able to formulate it in a way that doesn't use bases, and I don't see how to do that here.

Comment: Also, could you expand on the second sentence a bit?  Is there some obvious morphism from $\operatorname{Spec} A \otimes_K R$ involved here?

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of something else. $A$ is not necessarily commutative, so we can't talk about its spectrum.

Comment: Concerning the basis issue: Characteristic polynomials of linear maps are usually defined using determinants, and these can be expressed basis-free using exterior powers. Since every algebra $A$ embeds canonical into $\mathrm{End}(V)$, where $V$ is the underlying vector space, the general case of algebras can be reduced to linear maps. I think the paper is a little bit pretentious ...

Comment: Yeah, I know how to do it that way, but the goal of the paper (as I understood it) was to avoid that sort of thing and just have the characteristic polynomial pop out automatically without having to think about anything.

Comment: I do like the idea that the characteristic polynomial is just the minimal polynomial of, say, $\begin{pmatrix} t_{11} & t_{12} \\ t_{21} & t_{22} \end{pmatrix}$; I was just hoping there was some way to view that as an automatic consequence of the geometry of $\operatorname{End} V$.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I disagree. The author clearly states at the introduction that his intention is to provide an *alternative* approach to the construction of the characteristic polynomial (he even mentions the construction of determinants using exterior powers).